# How does pytorch automatically know what are my model's parameters?

Tags: python, pytorch

I have defined the custom class as follows:

```
class MLPClassifier(nn.Module):
    """
    A basic multi-layer perceptron classifier with 3 layers.
    """
  
    def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size, num_classes):
        """
        The constructor for the MLPClassifier class.
        """
        super(MLPClassifier, self).__init__()

        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(input_size, hidden_size)  # weights & biases for the input-to-hidden layer
        self.ac1 = nn.ReLU()                           # non-linear activation for the input-to-hidden layer
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(hidden_size, num_classes) # weights & biases for the hidden-to-output layer
        self.ac2 = nn.Softmax(dim=1)                   # non-linear activation for the hidden-to-output layer
```

When I run the following script I get this:

```
hyper_param_input_size  = 4
hyper_param_hidden_size = 64
hyper_param_num_classes = 3

model = MLPClassifier(hyper_param_input_size, hyper_param_hidden_size, hyper_param_num_classes)

for p in model.parameters():
    print(p.shape)

>>> torch.Size([64, 4])
>>> torch.Size([64])
>>> torch.Size([3, 64])
>>> torch.Size([3])
```

How on earth does PyTorch automatically know about my internally defined attributes when I never explicitly told it? Does it loop through everything in the class and check if `isinstance(self, nn.Layer)` or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`nn.Module.parameters`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/nn/modules/module.html#Module.parameters) function will recursively go through all child modules of the parent and return all its parameters. It does not have to do with the actual structure of your `MLPClassifier` module. When defining a new submodule attribute inside your `__init__` the parent module will register it as a child module, this way their parameters (if any, *eg.* your `nn.ReLU` and `nn.Softmax` don't have any...) can later be accessed via the `parameters` call.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I must've missed this in the documentation which left me scratching my head.